# Ran into an error when creating a Prepared statement to login PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, login-page

I keep running into the error where PHP says "We're sorry we can't log you in." according to one of my conditions set even if login is correct and hence my Prepared system to avoid SQL injection fails.

So my code goes like this:

```
global $connected;

$post = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pwwd = $post['password'];
$usrn = $post['username'];
$usrn = mysqli_real_escape_string($connected, $usrn);
$pwwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connected, $pwwd);

if (strlen($usrn) != 0 && strlen($pwwd) != 0 && !empty($post)) {
    $usrn = stripslashes($usrn);
    $pwwd = stripslashes($pwwd);
    $hashFormat = '$2ysomenumber$';
    $salt = 'somehashobviously';
    $hashF_and_salt = $hashFormat.$salt;
    $pwwd = crypt($pwwd, $hashF_and_salt);

    if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        mysqli_select_db($connected, 'someDbname') or die('Database   select error');
    } else {
        die('Failed to connect to PHPMyAdmin').mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username=? AND     Password=?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connected);

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
        //Some error in here somewhere

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $usrn, $pwwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $check_usrn, $check_pwd);

        if (strcasecmp($usrn, $check_usrn) == 0) {
            if ($pwwd == $check_pwd) {
                echo '<h1 class="text-center">Matches</h1>';
                print_r($row);
            }

        } else {
            echo "<h1 class=text-center>We're sorry we can't log you     in.</h1>";
        }

    }

} else { //This is for strlen boolean cond
    echo "<h1 class='text-center'>Both fields must not be empty.    </h1>";
}
```

I used to use a login page without prepared statements which was working, but I realised I need to do this for better security. My database is working fine so the problem is near where I added the comment "//Some error in here somewhere".

I am a relatively new PHP programmer that is yet a first year student trying daring new things in the holidays! Will openly read all the help I get, thank you!

Comment: do a `var_dump($usrn, $check_usrn);` and you will see the problem in your code.

Comment: My $check_usrn and $check_pass are definitely NULL value from what I did. Now how do I fix it so they are not NULL value and the value that is to be checked in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i didn't see your connection code for connection to the database which is like this.
`$connected = msqli_connect(host,user,password,db_name) ;` than you don't need to call `mysqli_select_db()`function.

Secondly you are checking your connectinon from `mysqli_connect_errno()` function which return 0 as integer (not boolean) if no error code value for last `mysqli_connect()` function.

Third there is no need to  Initializes prepare statement.

Fourth is `mysqli_stmt_bind_reslut()` comes before the `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`. see note point in  [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Use `hash_equals()` function to match password instead of `===`. see the warning section in [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

```
$connected = msqli_connect(host,user,password,db_name) ;
 if(!$connected)
 {
     die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
 } 
    echo "Your connection is  successful . "
 if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connected,$query))
 {
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $usrn, $pwwd);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $check_usrn, $check_pwd);
       mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
       /* Now do Your Work */

 } else 
   {
      /* still prepare statement doesn't work */
   } `
```

Comment: Like I said no problem with the connection, i have linked it on another page. This is just the portion of the code i want YOU to see. But I will remove the unnecessary code. Thank you for ur input.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realised 2 of my lines were mixed up! I also changed the function to check for passwords in order for better security. If I had the reputation; I would definitely '+1' your comment. You have saved me a lot of time! Edit: How do prepared statements compare to PDO statements? Do you think I have sufficient security? Can you give me some SQL injections that I can test out which won't do harm to my database?

Comment: if this correct answer than ,Please choose as right answer. it will help me. For PDO & SQL Injection see this [site](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)